# Any way to protect app from being killed by low memory killer?

Tags: android

Yes, protect from being killed by the low memory killer. Are there any options in AndroidManifest.xml?

May app contains a service, which need to run all the time in the background.

My app is placed in system/app, running an important service. This is our design.

There are lots of apps running, I can't control others to save memory, but I want a way to let Android not kill me, just as Phone app and SystemUi.

In Android, apps with lower oom_adi are less likely being killed. To do so, just set (`application android:persistent="true"`).

Comment: Other than, Use Less Memory ... nope. That's not how operating systems work. You are running as an app, not a kernel process. Your app is no more important than any other app running in the userspace.

Answer (score 4):

> any way to protect app from being killed by low memory killer?

Not really. You can use `startForeground()` if you (and the user) believe that your service is part of the foreground user experience, though that will put a `Notification` in the status or system bar.

> need to run all the time in background

Users can and will get rid of your service whenever they want (e.g., via swiping your entry in the Recent Tasks list on Android 4.0+, via task killers, via Force Stop in Settings). An application that truly requires an everlasting service is doomed to failure.

Comment: Thank you! In fact, android has a way to do so.

Comment: By the way, here is the reason why low memory killer can't be worked around or cheated. http://debuggingisfun.blogspot.com/2014/03/android-foolproof-low-memory-killer.html

Answer (score 1):

Android is rather efficient and good at handling scenarios like this; As Commonsware pointed out above, as in

> Users can and will get rid of your service whenever they want

*your app is not in control of the user* which is what the OP's question is coming across as, attempting (rather feebly) to mitigate end-user's action and choice!

Rather than wasting energy in trying to "***defeat***" low memory killers, it would be better to  ***reconsider and redesign your app*** in such a way that it does not hog up resources which is where Android steps in and say "*hey, stop playing with my precious resources that I have dished out to your application or I will kill you*", quite literally!

Answer (score 0):

Look into using alarms instead of a long running service.  Most of the time you can accomplish the same thing without the service always being there.